# Android: Recents tasks list, android:excludeFromRecents="true" behaviour with android:launchMode="singleTop"

Tags: java, android, android-activity, launchmode

Basically i do not want to show my app activity task in recents app..Have only one activity in my app.

Here is my Activity details:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection|screenSize|screenLayout|mnc|mcc|navigation"            
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html#removing

> Device : Nexus 5X
>   Android Version: 6.0.1

**Scenario 1:**

1)Click on the app.

2)Press home button.

3)Click on recents list / overview screen.

**4)App not listed in recents list.**

**Scenario 2:**

1)Click on the app.

2)Click on recents list / overview screen.

**3)App listed in recents list.**

```
/**
 * If set, the new activity is not kept in the list of recently launched
 * activities.
 */
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS = 0x00800000;
```

whats the reason? Is  these below attributes something to do with it ?

```
android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

Thanks

Nithin

Comment: I believe `excludeFromRecents` is only effective if the activity is the *root* of its task. Is it?

Comment: u got that right i guess..im experimenting that behaviour now and update here..

Comment: @SnildDolkow update my behaviour what do you make of it? Scenario 1 is not root right? Scenario 2 its root right? excludeFromRecents behaviour wrong? or ami missing something?

Comment: same bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78862